# Spark Count(Column-Name) in Select clause

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I write following SQL query using Spark `DataFrame API`?

```scala
val dt = spark.sql("select Subject, (count(Student)*100 / (select count(DISTINCT Student) from StudentTable)) as PercentPassed from StudentTable where Marks > 35 GROUP BY Subject").show(false)
```

Here I want to get percentage of students passed (out of 100%) , in each subject.

Below is the DataFrame registered as `StudentTable`:

```
val data = Seq(
    ("S1","English",45),
    ("S1","Hindi",78),
    ("S1","Maths",67),
    ("S1","Science",23),
    ("S2","English",34),
    ("S2","Hindi",45),
    ("S2","Maths",88),
    ("S2","Science",65),
    ("S3","English",21),
    ("S3","Hindi",66),
    ("S3","Maths",63),
    ("S3","Science",44)
  )
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("Student","Subject","Marks")
df.createTempView("StudentTable")
```

Comment: Would the someone care to explain for -ve vote on the abve question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupBy` and then `aggregate` by a conditional `count`

```
df.groupBy($"Subject")
  .agg(
        count(when($"Marks" > 35, 1)) / 
        count($"Marks") * 100 as "PercentPassed")
```

**Explanation:**
First groupBy by subject.

Then in the aggregate, generate two counts:

- The first one filtering by a Marks value (passed)
- The second one count every row (total)

Then dividing the first by the second and multiplying by 100 to have the percentage

**RESULT**

```
+-------+-----------------+
|Subject|    PercentPassed|
+-------+-----------------+
|Science|66.66666666666666|
|English|33.33333333333333|
|  Hindi|            100.0|
|  Maths|            100.0|
+-------+-----------------+
```